# How to remove lazy-loading from first 6 images in Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development

I`m optimizing site with PageSpeed test tool.

How to remove lazy loading from 7 first thumbnails (featured images) in front page and categories? By default worpress lazy-loading **from 4th image**, but I need from 7th.. Can`t find solution.

This filter removes lazy loading from all images in whole website:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

This script removes from first 6 images, but only in *post content* (I need in categories and frontpage):

```php
function add_responsive_class($content) {
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));
    $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < min(6, $imgs->length); $i++) {
        $img = $imgs->item($i);
        $img->removeAttribute('loading');
    }
    $html = $document->saveHTML();
    return $html;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_responsive_class');
```

My thumbnail image code example:

```html
<img width="248" height="248" src="wp-content/uploads/b-248x248.jpg" class="gal-thumbnail wp-post-image" decoding="async" itemprop="image" loading="lazy" 
wp-content/uploads/berniukas-300x300.jpg 300w, 
wp-content/uploads/b.jpg 800w" sizes="(max-width: 248px) 100vw, 248px">
```

Can You help me?

Answer (score 1):

You would do this by filtering the threshold to change it from the default 3 to 6 via `wp_omit_loading_attr_threshold`:

See:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_omit_loading_attr_threshold/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_omit_loading_attr_threshold/

Comment: Super! You saved me!

Comment: @uniuni if this answered your question consider marking it as the correct answer by clicking the tick button under the voting controls